# Docker mount a read only mount point as volume

Tags: docker, file-permissions, docker-swarm, mounted-volumes

I need to create an LVM snapshot, mount it as read only, and then mount that folder (read only mount point) as volume in docker-compose.
But the problem is that I can't see the contents of that read only mount point inside the docker container, but the contents are visible on the host.
Is this even possible to achieve in a docker, I use `alpine: latest` image, and in it deploy borgmatic.
Part of docker-compose with volumes:

volumes:

- `borg-cache.data:/root/.cache/borg`
- `/mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap:/mnt/source/minio-storage-1.data_snap`

When I unmount this snapshot and create some files in `/mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap`, then I can see that files inside docker-container in: `/mnt/source/minio-storage-1.data_snap`

Comment: Are using root inside of the docker container? Maybe you need to allow read permissions to all users on you host with `sudo chmod +r /mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap`

Comment: Yes i use root inside docker container, and i can't change permissions when snap is mounted, the mesage is: chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap': Read-only file system. I mount snap with this command: mount -o nouuid -o ro -o norecovery

Comment: Can you provide the current permissions for this folder with `ls -l /mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap`? Another way is maybe to flag the mounted folder in your container as well. Update therefore the docker compose file with `/mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap:/mnt/source/minio-storage-1.data_snap:ro`

Comment: Thanks for answers, root@debian-86:/mnt/vg_docker/minio-storage-1.data_snap# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   37 Nov 12 12:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov 11 13:42 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1598 Nov 11 14:00 run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  513 Nov 11 12:20 runsvc.sh.   Inside docker continer there is no this files: /mnt/source/minio-storage-1.data_snap # ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Nov 11 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Nov 11 15:47 ..